# Printing each password beside each array [0]password [1]password and so on

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, csv

I have written this code to print A;password in a foreach loop.

---

```
$array = "A","B","C","D","E","F","G"
$theDatabaseFile = "C:\Users\saied\Documents\MyWork\test.csv"
foreach($a in $array)
{
    $password =  ([char[]]([char]33..[char]95) + ([char[]]([char]97..[char]126)) + 0..9 | sort {Get-Random})[0..8] -join ''
    $final = $a +";"+ $password 

     $final
}

output
A;pgf5I^4aQ
B;g.62aG9+u
C;7MW<j)x85
D;]2PNv<&Fc
E;9iB^JDyj8
F;|tYV6<Qmd
G;?!B>mwvys
```

But if i use 
"`| Set-Content $theDatabaseFile -Encoding ascii`" after `$final` and open my csv file. the file would only take the last in my array.

Comment: `Set-Content ` will over write the file each time. If you use `Add-Content` it does exactly what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are reassign `$final` in the loop so it always set to the current item. You have to create an **array** and store the passwords in it:

```
$passwords = @()
foreach($a in $array)
{
    $password =  ([char[]]([char]33..[char]95) + ([char[]]([char]97..[char]126)) + 0..9 | sort {Get-Random})[0..8] -join ''
    $final = $a +";"+ $password 
    $passwords += $final
    $final
}

$passwords | Set-Content $theDatabaseFile -Encoding ascii
```